# Titanium picker in Android always white text color

Tags: android, titanium, picker

I'am building a search system for a Android app in Titanium. One of the options is that you can select an area, with a picker.

But when you select a area the text is always white and I can't get it to black. Here's my code.

Search.js

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};
var apiHelper = require('apiHelper');
var that = this;
//$.ind.message = 'Ophalen van huidige locatie';
//$.ind.show();
$.ind.hide();
// REQUIRE THE HEADER BAR FROM headerBar controller
// we will pass our Home View so we can animate it when we click the menu button
var headerBar = Alloy.createController("adrHeaderBar", {
    parentView : $.winSearch,
    title : args.menuItem.title,
    isFlyout : args.isFlyout
}).getView();

$.winSearch.add(headerBar);

// Get Locations
var db = Ti.Database.open('DriveEatSleep');
var jsonRS = db.execute('SELECT * FROM locations');
var data = [];  
var i = 1;
data[0]=Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:"Selecteer streek/land"});
while (jsonRS.isValidRow())
{
data[i]=Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({title:jsonRS.fieldByName('name')});
i = i + 1;
jsonRS.next();
}
 db.close();
$.Area.add(data);
$.Area.setSelectedRow(0,1, false);
```

Search.tss

```
"#Area":{
left : '14dp',
    right : '14dp',
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    font: {
        fontFamily:'Arial',
        fontSize: '14dp',
        fontStyle: 'normal',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fontcolor:'black'
  },
    paddingLeft : '10dp',
    top:"15dp",
    borderWidth : '1dp',
    borderColor: "#000",
    backgroundColor:"#FFF",
    color:"#000"
}
"#areaView":{
    color:"#000"
}
```

And search.xml

```
<Alloy>

    <View id="winSearch">
    <ScrollView id='searchScroll'>
        <Label id='lblText'>Zoek op naam, plaats of adres</Label>

        <TextField id='txtName'></TextField>
        <Label id='lblOf'>OF</Label>
        <View id='areaView'>
        <Picker id='Area' selectionIndicator="true">

        </Picker>
        </View>

    </ScrollView>
    <ActivityIndicator id="ind" message="Ophalen van locatie...">
        </ActivityIndicator>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

Example whats going wrong
[image: example app]

Comment: This link will solve your problem https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/164315/cursor-color-in-a-textbox

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? I'm still getting this weird behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

A `Picker` does not have the property `font` and the color is not set through the `font`-object, but with the `color`-property (which a `Picker` does not have either).

You need add a `Label` with the desiredf `font` and `color` to your `PickerRow`s:

```
data[i] = Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
    layout: 'vertical'
});

data[i].add(Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    left: 0,
    text: jsonRS.fieldByName('name'),
    color: 'black',
    font: {
        fontFamily:'Arial',
        fontSize: '14dp',
        fontStyle: 'normal',
        fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
}));
```

Comment: Ah, yes. My mistake. Those properties are only available on Tizen and MobileWeb. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hmm, now I'am just getting this: Image: http://development.webor.nl/files/screenshot_3.png